# Where is easy.c and curl.c in libcurl?

Tags: c, libcurl, http2, nghttp2

I want to make the fastest http2 request in c. So I decided to open curl & nghttp2. I can find nghttp.cc in nghttp github, but cannot find curl.c & easy.c. I found only curl.h & easy.h. Where can I find those source files? I want to see source of curl_easy_perform, curl_init, etc... Is there anyone can help?

Comment: The source is here: [libcurl](https://github.com/curl/curl)

Comment: I understand!! Thx!!

Comment: i don't think `curl.c` exists. easy.c is in the lib folder though

Comment: Thx hanshenrik! Then.. where can i find source of curl_global_init & curl_global_cleanup???

Comment: I found it inside easy.c.